# Insert Query not inserting when all column names are 100% correct

Tags: php, pdo

```
$UniqueID = rand(5400, 40000);
$InsertQuery = $c->prepare("INSERT INTO dbo.Users_Master ( 
UserUID, UserID, Pw, JoinDate, Admin, AdminLevel, UseQueue, Status, Leave, UserType, Point)
VALUES (:UserUID, :UserID, :Pw, :Date, :Admin, :AdminLevel, :UseQue, :Status, :Leave, :UserType, :Point)");
$Param = array ($UniqueID, $_POST['Username'], $_POST['Password'], '2013-21-10', 'False', '0', 'False', '0', '0', 'P', '0');
$InsertQuery->execute($Param);
```

Hello. My above code does have the correct column names/table name for my database, but my insert is not working? Can anyone see why?

---

I have went over this query like 10 times, trying to spot the mistake but I just cant try it. I have tried binding the params the traditional way:

```
$InsertQuery->bindParam(':UserUID', $UniqueID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$InsertQuery->bindParam(':UserID', $_POST['Username'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$InsertQuery->bindParam(':Pw', $_POST['Password'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$InsertQuery->bindParam(':Date', '2013-21-10', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$InsertQuery->bindParam(':Admin', 'False', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$InsertQuery->bindParam(':AdminLevel', '0', PDO::PARAM_INT);
$InsertQuery->bindParam(':UseQue', '0', PDO::PARAM_INT);
$InsertQuery->bindParam(':Status', '0', PDO::PARAM_INT);
$InsertQuery->bindParam(':Leave', '0', PDO::PARAM_INT);
$InsertQuery->bindParam(':UserType', 'P', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$InsertQuery->bindParam(':Point', '0', PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

This proven no luck either.

Comment: What is the layout of the table you are trying to insert into?

Comment: And are you getting any error?

Comment: Don't you find your code a quite repetitive one?

Comment: `$UniqueID = rand(5400, 40000);` so the odds are `1/34600` to have twice the same "unique" ID (at the beginning)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"trying to spot the mistake" is **extremely** inefficient way to spot a mistake.
A programmer have to ask their program to do so.

IN case with PDO issues one have to tell PDO to raise an error on error:

```
$c->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```

have to be set right after connect, or even better - as a connect option.
it will retell you whatever error occurred in database - so, you will know, what's going wrong.

There are also some issues with your code

1. Never call a random number an unique. Make this field auto_increment PRIMARY KEY instead and let database keep uniqueness for you.
2. Do not bind constants. that's just boring.
3. Shorten your code. But reasonably: long line doesn't make your code shorter

so

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Users_Master VALUES (NULL,?,?,curdate(),'False',0,0,0,0,'P',0)";
$stmt = $c->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($_POST['Username'], $_POST['Password']));
```

Comment: curdate() is not a function in MSSQL